# Zend Framework session problem on IE

Tags: php, zend-framework, session

I have a problem with zend session.If i don't define expire date parameter for session while using it, and i close the browser in firefox the session destroyed.However, in IE it doesn't.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Propably you let firefox delete all cookies on exit and IE not. Thats how sessions work ;)

Comment: Hi KingCrunch,i ask this for security problem.IE users may not adjust this property(if ie has delete cookies on exit)

Answer (score 0):

There are several parameters that can be manipulated to change the behavior of the PHP session management. These parameters are set in the php.ini file in the section headed [Session].

look for:

session.cookie_lifetime

This parameter holds the life of a session cookie in seconds and is used by PHP when setting the expiry date and time of a cookie. The default value of 0 sets up a session cookie that lasts only while the browser program is running. Setting this value to a number of seconds other than 0 sets up the cookie with an expiry date and time. The expiry date and time of the cookie is set as an absolute date and time, calculated by adding the cookie_lifetime value to the current date and time on the server machine.

[ The actual expiry of the cookie is performed by the browser, which compares the expiry date and time of the cookie with the client machine's date and time. If the date and time are incorrectly set on the client, a cookie might expire immediately or persist longer than expected. ]

Comment: Hi bensiu,session.cookie_lifetime is set to 0